# Is there any way to display your last name first on Google Plus/Google products?

Tags: google-plus, google-account-profile

In some cultures last names are normally written before the first name, e.g. in East Asia as well as Turkey. Facebook offers you this option to display your name in this order. However I don't see any such option on Google Plus, and therefore this also seems to be impossible if I want to link to my Google Plus profile when using other Google products. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't offer to change the order of the name. Google offer to [add a nickname or other name to your Google+ profile](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3298988). In this you can put your name in any order.

Or alternate is write your last name in first name and first name in last name section. Changing your name on Google+ will also change it in other Google products, like YouTube and Google Wallet.